# expected enum `winapi::ctypes::c_void`

Tags: файлы, winapi, rust

Не могу понять, что это за ошибка и как её исправить:

```
file.as_raw_handle()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `winapi::ctypes::c_void`, found enum `std::ffi::c_void`
```

```
pub fn unlock(file: &File) -> Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        let ret = UnlockFile(file.as_raw_handle(), 0, 0, !0, !0);
        if ret == 0 { Err(Error::last_os_error()) } else { Ok(()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это разные типы, объявленные в разных местах - один c_void из winapi, другой из стандартной либы. Поскольку это просто указатели на нечто, то должно помочь преобразование типов через as.

Comment: @ozkriff я добавил use `fs2::FileExt` и всё заработало, эта функция работает, только если файл открыт моим процессом `OpenOptions...`, но я хотел реализовать удаление файла, который занят другим процессом, есть ли какая то информация, не могу никак найти.

Comment: Пока файл где-то используется, его удаление невозможно.